# Unable to display products in flat table even after reindexing

Tags: magento2.4, reindex, flat-catalog

I imported few products in magento2.4 and also enable Flat tables through configuration.
After that I tried to run php bin/magento indexer:reindex but didn't display that product in catalog_product_flat_1

Also I tried to run cache flush commands but still not displayed in flat tables nor in frontend

Comment: Does that products are enable and direct able to view the product by URL or not?

Comment: No I checked issue is related to during product import not able to save status and visibility by default. Any solution for this ?

Comment: check the console or log, is there anything show during import.